# Yahoo Pipes: String tokenizer won't accept {

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I am trying to parse some JSON output from a web service using yahoo pipes and whenever I try to use a `{` in the string tokenizer it breaks the pipe.

Is it a protected/special character or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, figures as soon as I post this I figure it out.

For some reason { is a special character where } is not.

In order to use { I prefixed it with .